# post not send form data

Tags: html, codeigniter, post

I have a problem with sending posts in codeigniter, reading other posts I set the variable `max_input_vars = 1000`. but does not send the data.
the resulting in `html` is:

```
<form id="0" action="CO_controller" method="post">
<input id="idric_0" value="0.02508800 154401490122">
<input id="name_0" value="val0">
<input id="per_0" value="10">
<input id="unit_0" value="g">
<input id="ric_0" value="0.02508800 1544014901">
<input id="command0">
<input id="mod0" type="submit" value="Modific" onclick="document.getElementById('command0').value = 'modific';">
<input id="eli0" type="submit" value="Deleta" onclick="document.getElementById('command0').value = 'deleta';">
<input id="id_sal0" value="0.02508800 1544014901">
</form> 
<form id="1" action="CO_controller" method="post">
<input id="idric_1" value="0.02508800 154401490122">
<input id="name_1" value="val0">
<input id="per_1" value="10">
<input id="unit_1" value="g">
<input id="ric_1" value="0.02508800 1544014901">
<input id="command1">
<input id="mod1" type="submit" value="Modific" onclick="document.getElementById('command1').value = 'modific';">
<input id="eli1" type="submit" value="Deleta" onclick="document.getElementById('command1').value = 'deleta';">
<input id="id_sal1" value="0.02508800 1544014901">
</form>
```

the operation is correct ie when I click the button, set the value of the command and submit.
in debug, I go to see the variable `$ _POST` and it is empty

Comment: Try to use `name` as the attribute name instead of `id`

Comment: Opsss... ok send

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment, you should use `name` instead of `id`. By using id you are not passing the values correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a route defined so that `CO_controller` points to a method (and not just a controller) this is not going to work:

```
<form id="0" action="CO_controller" method="post">
```

Your form action should point directly to the method within the `CO_controller` controller which will process the form input.

Assuming the method within the controller is called `process_form` your form should point to:

```
<form id="0" action="CO_controller/process_form" method="post">
```

give it a go and let us know how it works